# Tags get populated multiple times on editing a question

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, android-app

The tags are populated multiple times on editing own question.

[image: Tags squared!]

[Got it again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzEAx.png). Not sure of how to replicate.

Version: 0.1.19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was found to be a bug when rotating the screen during editing.  It will be fixed in v0.1.20 - coming to a droid near you.